# How to add large number of static files to MonoTouch bundle?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have (quite a bit of) static files that I need to deploy with my application that is built on top of a legacy .NET library. These include several XML and config files, and a read-only database in the 10's of Megabytes.

Most forums I have seen indicate that the best way to accomplish this is to reference the needed files in a project, and set them to Content and "Copy to Output Directory".

I have two issues/questions dealing with this:

1. Adding these files, and setting them to "Content" seems to not only copy the files over, but embed them into the .dll as well. In other words, I have 40 MB worth of files, and a 40MB dll (this project's only goal is to import these files, there is no substantial code). 
   **How can I prevent this extremely large dll from being made?**
2. Is there an alternative way to get files into the App bundle? I would love to use a custom build command, and although I can copy files into the target directory ${AppDirectory}, but this does not result in these files ending up in the app bundle. **Is this approach possible?**

Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include your files from the main **.exe** project. You do this by using MonoDevelop's **Build Action** to **Content** on each file. They should be copied to the .app without being included inside an .dll (or the .exe).

An alternative (for development) is to use [iTunes sharing](http://jamesantrobus.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/itunes-file-sharing-with-monotouch/) to copy **once** your files to your device. This allows you **much** faster deployment times while developing.

Of course you can't submit such build to the app store (unless the files are not required to make the application work, unlikely). What I do (for my nearly 80MB read-only database) is to use this *hack* (loading from /Documents) inside `#if DEBUG`. The release build load the files from the *normal* location.

I have not automated the process (still debugging the app ;-) but it should be possible to script this so modifying the project options (for each file) is not required when switching from Debug and Release builds.

Comment: How necessary is it that the files are part of the main executable project? Why can't they be part of a library project? We would ideally have many target executables used by this library. Extra pain is added when the library was built with >50 read-only xml (and other configurations) files required to run, since I can't just stick them in some subfolder and still maintain the proper file hierarchy that the library expects.

Comment: It won't be necessary in MonoDevelop 3.1 (assuming that the library projects are MonoTouch Library projects)